# SELECIONAR DUAS COLUNAS QUE TEM O MESMO ID EM TABELAS DIFERENTE E FAZER COMPARAÇÕES

Tags: sql, mysqli, sql-select, mysql

[image: Primeira tabela chamada actor]
[image: Segunda tabela chamada film_actor]

Boa noite Devs,

Preciso pegar cada actor_id e film_id e verificar qual o total de filmes(filme_id) que tem vinculado ao actor_id e isso eu consegui : `SELECT actor_id, COUNT(film_id) from film_actor group by actor_id;`

Depois disso e que é minha duvida agora, é pegar o first_name e actor_id da tabela actor e comparar com o ID da tabela film_actor

Estou utilizando o Banco de Dados Sakilla que vem com o MySQL WorkBench

- > A tarefa do professor: Selecione o primeiro nome (first_name) e o total de filmes que cada ator/atriz (actor) está associado(a) (usar COUNT e GROUP BY). (0,3)

Answer (score -3):

Resolvido usando o codigo abaixo = SELECT actor.first_name, count(film_actor.actor_id) AS 'TOTAL'
FROM actor INNER JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
GROUP BY film_actor.actor_id;